# how to replace the \n in java?

Tags: java, android

I have working in Facebook for my app in Android. I have to use the string to pass as a url. But my description value has a lot of spaces and line breaks. I have to rectify while passing that value as url without spaces. But it will poste on the facebook wall with the spaces. Is it possible? Any Idea.

Comment: Can you rephrase this question? I do not understand what you are trying to ask because your English is a little bit unwieldy.

Comment: why can't you just use regex and replace the characters you don't want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When generating your URL parameters, use:

```
paramString = URLEncoder.encode(paramString, "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're asking how to properly encode the URL so it has no whitespace, or if you want to remove line breaks from a string.  If you want to remove line breaks from a string, do this:

```
yourString.replaceAll("\n", "");
```